# start end div after some elements php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I cannot solve problem with starting ending divs after couple of elements from array.
What i want to get is something like that:

```
<div>
element1
element2
element3
element4
</div>

<div>
element5
element6
element7
element8
</div>

<div>
element9
element10
</div>
```

Here is my php code:

```
$array = array("element1","element2","element3","element4","element5","element6","element7","element8","element9","element10");
$perRow = 4;
$count = 1;
foreach ($array as $arr){
    // here div needs to start, use 4 elements from array and close
    if($count % $perRow == 0 OR $count == 1){
        echo '<div>';
    }
    echo $arr . '<br>';

    // here should div close


    $count++;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$array = array("element1","element2","element3","element4","element5","element6","element7","element8","element9","element10");
$perRow = 4;
$count = 0;
echo '<div>';
foreach ($array as $arr){
    // here div needs to start, use 4 elements from array and close
    if($count % $perRow == 0 && $count!=0){
        echo '</div><div>';
    }
    echo $arr . '<br>';

    // here should div close


    $count++;

}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: ok try this take $count=0 and put 1 more condition in if $count!=0 and it will works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am not familiar with arrays and maybe something like this would work:

```
$array = array("element1","element2","element3","element4","element5","element6","element7","element8","element9","element10");

$i=0;

echo '<div>'

if (i<3) {
echo '$array[$i]';
$i++;
}

echo '</div>';
echo '<div>';

if ($i>3 && $i<7)  {
echo '$array[$i]';
$i++;
}

echo '</div>';
echo '<div>';
if ($i>7 && $i<10)  {
echo '$array[$i]';
$i++;
}
echo '</div>';
```